# Google SAML APP SSO integrate with php application

Tags: php, single-sign-on, saml, google-workspace

I am using the php [SAML library](https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml/tree/master/demo2) for SAML integration in php applucation(SP) with google as IDP.
I followed the step for the configuration of SAML toolkit for PHP in this [link](https://developers.onelogin.com/saml/php).

- I add application SAML Test Connector (IdP w/ attr).
- I add the content of repository Github to my hosting to run PHP code.
- I defined the variable in demo1/settings.php

Setting code image

[image: 3]

But I am getting a response from google suit (IDP)

google IDP response

[image: 4]

Even I had tried he same code with Onelogin as IDP and it was working. Don't know why it's not working with Google as IDP.

Please Help! if anyone having an idea for the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Hey, were you able to solve this issue? I'm facing the same issue with the same bundle using google as idp provider. With microsoft azure as idp it works perfectly.

Comment: I just added the binding attribute in the settings. and it worked for me.
 'binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST',